# Strange behavior using Generalized Lambda Capture

Tags: c++

Basically, I was trying to write a C++ code to transform a `vector<int>` into a `vector<pair<int, int> >` where each entry of the output means `<x, frequency x appears together>`. For example, `{1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3}` would become `{(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3)}`.

As a competitive programmer, **readability or good practices are not priorities** (I don't wanna change the way I am doing stuff). The problem is that the second lambda, which uses a [Generalized Lambda Capture](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#lambda-captures), has a strange behavior.

My code:

```cpp
    vector<int> a = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4};

    vector<ii> b(a.size()); // the output
    // accumulates the frequency of the element at b[i].second, going backwards
    transform(a.rbegin(), a.rend(), b.rbegin(), [prev=make_pair(-1, 0)](int x) mutable {
        return prev = x == prev.first? ii(prev.first, prev.second + 1) : make_pair(x, 1);
    });
    // Now, b is {(1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 3), (3, 2), (3, 1), (4, 2), (4, 1)}

    // removes the elements that are equal to the previous, leaving only the first appearences
    b.erase(remove_if(b.begin(), b.end(), [prev=make_pair(-1, 0)](auto x) mutable {
        return prev.first == (prev = x).first;
    }), b.end());

    // Now, b *should* be {(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 2)}
    // But, b is {(1, 3), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 2)}
```

The issue is that on the third call of the lambda in the `remove_if` function, `prev` is "reseted" to being `make_pair(-1, 0)`, I don't know why... This way, `(1, 1)` appears in the final array, because the lambda returns  false.

Check out the code with debugs:

```cpp
    vector<int> a = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4};

    vector<ii> b(a.size());
    transform(a.rbegin(), a.rend(), b.rbegin(), [prev=make_pair(-1, 0)](int x) mutable {
        return prev = x == prev.first? ii(prev.first, prev.second + 1) : ii(x, 1);
    });

    b.erase(remove_if(b.begin(), b.end(), [prev=make_pair(-1, 0)](auto x) mutable {
        cout << cnt++ << " " << prev.first << ' ' << prev.second << ' ' << x.first << ' ' << x.second << endl;
        return  prev.first == (prev = x).first;
    }), b.end());
```

and what it prints:

```
0 -1 0 1 3
1 1 3 1 2
2 -1 0 1 1 <---- this "-1 0" should be "1 2"
3 1 1 2 2
4 2 2 2 1
5 2 1 3 4
6 3 4 3 3
7 3 3 3 2
8 3 2 3 1
9 3 1 4 2
```

Am I doing something wrong there which is causing some sort of undefined behavior? Thank you!

Comment: Standard algorithms are allowed to copy the predicate as many times as they want. `std::remove_if` in particular is often implemented to call `std::find_if` first, and so does exercise this right of making a copy (whereas `std::tansform` doesn't need to). This means that stateful predicates must arrange to share state between copies. For example, make `prev` a "normal" local variable outside the lambda, capture it by reference in the lambda; this way, all copies of that lambda will refer to the same variable.

Comment: So when the predicate is "copied", that means 2 variables `prev` will "exist" right? That makes sense! Thanks

Comment: A lambda is an object of some unnamed class type synthesized by the compiler. `prev` is a data member of that class. When a lambda is copied, its members are copied too, just as with any class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutating the predicate in `remove_if` is not safe: the order of evaluation (yes, really!) and whether or not the predicate is "recopied" midway is unspecified. The standard algorithms intentionally have vague specifications to allow a lot of latitude in implementation. If you *need* to visit the elements in order, you need to do it yourself (or use `std::for_each`). This is just as well: your proposed method with the multiple runs over the data in opposite directions and the shifting of elements etc. is overcomplicated. You need one iteration made in chunks.

```
template<typename T>
auto runs(std::vector<T> const &data) {
    std::vector<std::pair<T, int>> ret;
    for(auto begin = data.begin(), end = begin; begin != data.end(); begin = end) {
        end = std::find_if_not(begin, data.end(), [&x = *begin](auto const &y) { return x == y; });
        ret.emplace_back(*begin, std::distance(begin, end));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:100,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:9,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:100,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:9,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aauto+runs(std::vector%3CT%3E+const+%26data)+%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cstd::pair%3CT,+int%3E%3E+ret%3B%0A++++for(auto+begin+%3D+data.begin(),+end+%3D+begin%3B+begin+!!%3D+data.end()%3B+begin+%3D+end)+%7B%0A++++++++end+%3D+std::find_if_not(begin,+data.end(),+%5B%26x+%3D+*begin%5D(auto+const+%26y)+%7B+return+x+%3D%3D+y%3B+%7D)%3B%0A++++++++ret.emplace_back(*begin,+std::distance(begin,+end))%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+ret%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::vector+a%7B1,+1,+1,+2,+2,+3,+3,+3,+3,+4,+4%7D%3B%0A++++for(auto+const+%26%5Bx,+n%5D+:+runs(a))+std::cout+%3C%3C+x+%3C%3C+%22:+%22+%3C%3C+n+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:66.42174871418075,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:clang_trunk,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.57825128581925,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your implementation. It's really nice indeed. I did it my way to practice using functional c++, and mutable lambdas